# Backbone Stickit erases dinamically rendered inputs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I render some inputs dinamically with javascript. Example:

```
render: function (id, val) {
            return '<input id="' + id + '" value="' + val + '"/>'
        }
```

After that I call `this.stickit();` in my view render function but it erases values of rendered inputs (I guess it's because of model is empty).

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround but I'm not sure it's a good way. The idea is to disable
updates of view coming from a model:

```
bindings: {
            '#id_of_input': {
                observe: 'name_of_attribute',
                updateView: false,
                setOptions: {
                    validate: true
                },
                events: ['change', 'blur', 'focus']
            }
 }
```

But after we rendered an input and filled it with a data we must trigger `'change'` event on the input to update bounded model attribute.

This is a good solution for now because I don't use my model to update a view.
But in case we want two-way binding (model <-> view) I still don't know the solution.